# No Mongoose db showing up after using mongoose.connect and creating a mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I am trying to connect a mongoose database to my project using Node js, Express and Mongoose and I have run into a weird problem. After connecting to a mongoose database successfully and specifying a model, nothing seems to show up in my collections (i.e no schemas). However when I do the command use "my new database" it switches to that database. I have looked all over the place and cannot seem to find the issue and I'm pretty sure my code is correct. Below is my code

importing model and creating database:

```
const Item = require("./models/Item"),

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/SurfShareDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Your Database has been connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERROR", err.message);
  });
```

Item schema and model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  description: String,
  price: String,
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  author: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
    },
    username: String,
  },
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collection in MongoDB is not created until something is written to either a document in the collection, an index on the collection, or to the collection's metadata.